# Update and convert a query using vba editor in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have a question regarding Excel VBA with queries. I would like to automate a few steps using VBA that I would otherwise have to do manually. I am doing the following steps:

I download the data using the API from [www.coingecko.com](http://www.coingecko.com). For this I use the following formula

`= Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&ids=nano%2Ccardano%2Cbitcoin%2Cethereum%2Ceos&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"))`

I can already figure out how to customize it. The problem is the following steps. I convert the data into a table and show only certain columns. I just don't know how to do this with VBA.

I'm just getting started with queries, so I'm stuck at this point. Can someone maybe help me?

Comment: Did you try PowerQuery? Why do you want to use VBA specifically?

Comment: I think I found the solution with your tip, thank you!

Comment: Great! glad to help. Just mark this question as answered so it doesn't pop up in unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options,

1. Powerquery
2. Macro
3. User Defined Function

Try this and let us know if this helps.